# Windows 2008 Remote Desktop will not copy+paste

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop

I have just set up a Guest Windows 2008 R2 Standard Edition 64bit (VirtualBox on Windows 7 64 bit host) for some testing.

I have found that while "inside" the remote desktop environment (i.e. I remote onto the guest ip from the host) that copy and paste does not work. When I say "does not work" let me be explicit.

- Assume I am logged onto the Win2008 machine via RDC
- Nothing is in the copy/paste buffer. I can mouse click some text and then rclick copy. I can then right click and click "paste" but nothing happens. I can see the "choice" is enabled to paste bu nothing happens. The caret stays put.
- CTRL+C / CTRL-V / CTRL-X does not work in RDC land
- I am not talking about going in-between copy/paste RDC land/host land.

HERE is the double whammy: when I do the above it then "infects" my host pc so that copy paste is unavailable there too. if PRT SCR doesn't work any more.

I have tried:

- restarting the guest os and host os
- in group policy editor I have disabled "do not allow clip board redirection" ( I can't give you the full path to this copy/paste just broke again)
- I have made sure that in RDC "options" for local resources include clipboard.
- NB: if I don't touch RDC at all and log into the guest OS via the console copy paste works perfectly

Answer (score 8):

Kill the `rdpclip.exe` process using the Task Manager. Then, create a new process named `rdpclip.exe`. This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 7):

Follow these steps in Remote Machine.

### **Stop the rdpclip process**

1. Open Task Manager.
2. Go to process tab and find `rdpclip`
3. Choose `rdpclip` and End that task.

### **Start rdpclip.exe**

4. Go to start menu and open Run command
5. Open **rdpclip.exe** and click Ok button.

[image]

Copy paste should work now.

Answer (score 1):

it appears this is a flaw with VirtualBox

these posts covers it

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=44498 (read the last post)

https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/issues/230

Answer (score 1):

(In VirtualBox) SETTINGS->GENERAL->[Advanced]->Shared Clipboard {disabled}

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things to check.

Restarting **rdpclip.exe** is a worthy try if the copy/paste fails sporadically, meaning we might on a process in a previous session.

On the client side, we check the RDP Options. Click on the Show Options button in the bottom, pick the third tab **Local Resources**. Make sure **Clipboard** is checked.

[image: rdp]

On the remote server side, we want to check **Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration** (Win Server 2008+).

[image]

Double click the connection to open its Properties window.

[image]

In the tab named **Client Settings**, Make sure **Clipboard** is not disabled.

[image]

We need to log off from the remote desktop.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

### Workaround

Use an online shared text box like this one:

https://pastebin.com/